# how to use .sass files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sass

I'm trying to use sass files in an ASP.NET web project. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Here is the sass stylesheet that i'm trying to use in my project :

```
$red: rgba(255,74,86,1)
.transition
@include transition( all 0.25s cubic-bezier(.53,.01,.35,1.5))

*
font-family: Helvetica , sans-serif
font-weight: light
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased

html
background-color: $red //rgba(245,248,252,1)

form
position: relative
display: inline-block
max-width: 700px
min-width: 500px
box-sizing: border-box
padding: 30px 25px
background-color: white
border-radius: 40px
margin: 40px 0
left: 50%
@include translate( -50% , 0 )

h1
color: $red
font-weight: 100
letter-spacing: 0.01em
margin-left: 15px
margin-bottom: 35px
text-transform: uppercase

button
@extend .transition
margin-top: 35px
background-color: white
border: 1px solid $red
line-height: 0
font-size: 17px
display: inline-block
box-sizing: border-box
padding: 20px 15px 
border-radius: 60px
color: $red
font-weight: 100
letter-spacing: 0.01em
position: relative
z-index: 1

&:hover , &:focus
  color: white
  background-color: $red

.question
position: relative
padding: 10px 0

&:first-of-type
  padding-top: 0

&:last-of-type
  padding-bottom: 0

label
  @extend .transition
  transform-origin: left center
  color: $red
  font-weight: 100
  letter-spacing: 0.01em
  font-size: 17px
  box-sizing: border-box
  padding: 10px 15px
  display: block
  position: absolute
  margin-top: -40px
  z-index: 2
  pointer-events: none

input[type="text"]
  @extend .transition
  appearance: none
  background-color: none
  border: 1px solid $red
  line-height: 0
  font-size: 17px
  width: 100%
  display: block
  box-sizing: border-box
  padding: 10px 15px
  border-radius: 60px
  color: $red
  font-weight: 100
  letter-spacing: 0.01em
  position: relative
  z-index: 1

  &:focus
    outline: none
    background: $red
    color: white
    margin-top: 30px

  &:valid
    margin-top: 30px

  &:focus ~ label
    @include translate( 0 , -35px )

  &:valid ~ label
    text-transform: uppercase
    font-style: italic
    @include transform( translate( 5px , -35px ) scale(0.6))
```

which i got it from [this site](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYBQyJ)

is the any way to use that style in my project ?

Comment: Did you try *installing* Sass?

Comment: no, how to install it, i'm not familiar with visual studio

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rtm.aspx.  Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 has native support for Sass.  If it isn't working, and you are on a correct Visual Studio Version, you should update your question with any errors you receive when trying to reference your file.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/11/16/working-with-sass-stylesheets-in-asp-net-mvc-applications-and-visual-studio) recommends that you use [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench). It appears Web Essentials has SASS support, also.

Edit: As Claies mentions in the comments, it appears there's native support in VS 2013 Update 2.